# yasnippet and backslashes

Tags: emacs, auctex, yasnippet

I have installed yasnippet 0.8 from elpa on emacs 24 and I want to write a snippet that inserts this text into a LaTeX document (using AUCTeX):

```
\\

\vspace{10pt}
```

So I have this snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: para
# key: para
# binding: direct-keybinding
# expand-env: ((some-var some-value))
# type: command
# --
\\\\

\\vspace{10pt}
```

but when I type `para<TAB>` all that happens is that the text `para` is removed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using some defaults that shouldn't be there. Change it to:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: para
# key: para
# --
\\\\

\\vspace{10pt}
```